# How to make tmp writable for cakephp in GAE(Google App Engine)?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cakephp, tmp

I have deployed an app to GAE, the project is running but it's giving following error, can anyone help me out.
I am unable to change permissions for tmp folder.
I have created bucket in app engine with tmp but it didn'yt worked out.

I have been following these steps :
[http://dev-mcconnell.blogspot.co.uk/](http://Steps) but it didn't worked out.

```
Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in /base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/1.382178581226787521/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 309 Warning: /base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/1.382178581226787521/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/1.382178581226787521/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 336 Warning: /base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/1.382178581226787521/app/tmp/cache/models/ is not writable in /base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/1.382178581226787521/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 336

Warning (512): /base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/1.382178581226787521/app/tmp/cache/ is not writable [CORE/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 336]

Warning (2): session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/1.382178581226787521/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:309) [APP/Controller/WebBaseController.php, line 21]

Warning (2): session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/1.382178581226787521/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:309) [APP/Controller/WebBaseController.php, line 21]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_my-project_list' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_my-project_list' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_my-project_user_fields' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_my-project_user_fields' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_my-project_user_categories' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_my-project_user_categories' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_my-project_sliders' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_my-project_sliders' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_my-project_news' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_my-project_news' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_my-project_countries' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_my-project_countries' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]
```

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine is a read-only filesystem.

I suspect trying to use Google's Blob Storage as file cache will not give you the performance benefits expected - even if you could set it up to work.

If caching is required, I recommend using Memcache if possible.

Comment: I have used APC for now. Do you have some idea which one is better for GAE (APC or Memcache)

Comment: It depends on your requirements. Memcache will be shared between instances of your application. APC will not.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I think i need to have a closer eye on it.